# What dependencies should be included when deploying a Spark application to EMR 6.x?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, gradle, amazon-emr

I have a Spark application that I'm able to run locally. The dependencies I have are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${scalaVersion}"

    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:${sparkVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.12:${sparkVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.12:${sparkVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.12:${sparkVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:${sparkVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.12', version: "${sparkVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-hive_2.12', version: "${sparkVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-yarn_2.12', version: "${sparkVersion}"
    testImplementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-catalyst_2.12', version: "${sparkVersion}"


    implementation group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-aws', version: hadoop_version
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb.spark', name: 'mongo-spark-connector_2.12', version: '3.0.1'
    testImplementation "com.holdenkarau:spark-testing-base_2.12:${sparkVersion}_1.1.0"
}
```

When looking at the Spark docs, it lists a version matrix https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-6x.html explaining what dependencies are provided.

The documentation also points to a separate Maven-compliant repository that should be used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-artifact-repository.html and I'm unsure if that should be added like so (alongside Maven Central):

```
repositories {
      maven {
          url "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1-emr-artifacts/emr-6.2.0/repos/maven/"
      }
      mavenCentral()
}
```

From what I've understood, certain dependencies are already provided by EMR and those have custom Spark enhancements.

My cluster is created using the following command:

```
aws emr create-cluster --auto-scaling-role myprod-emr-auto-scaling --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Pig Name=Hue Name=Spark --bootstrap-actions '[{"Path":"s3://my-emr-bootstrap/sshkeys.sh","Name":"Add ssh keys"}]' --ebs-root-volume-size 20 --ec2-attributes '{"KeyName":"mridang_test","InstanceProfile":"myprod-emr","ServiceAccessSecurityGroup":"sg-xxxxxxxx","SubnetId":"subnet-xxxxxxxx","EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup":"sg-xxxxxxxx","EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup":"sg-xxxxxxxx"}' --service-role myprod-emr-service --enable-debugging --release-label emr-6.2.0 --log-uri 's3n://aws-logs-0123456789-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/' --name 'MridangTest' --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":2}]},"InstanceGroupType":"CORE","InstanceType":"c5a.xlarge","Name":"Core - 2"},{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":2}]},"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","InstanceType":"c5a.xlarge","Name":"Master - 1"}]' --scale-down-behavior TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION --region us-east-1
```

How should my build be configured so that I can correctly only include the necessary libs into my ZIP project? There's a fair amount of collateral around this topic but nothing cohesive that explains how to configure it all.

My setup is tied to Gradle unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a fat jar with dependencies, as almost all the `org.apache.spark.*` dependencies are available on your cluster and are included in the classpath.

So in your case, you can mark all your `org.apache.*` dependencies as provided (i.e. compile only in Gradle https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/release-notes.html#support-for-declaring-compile-time-only-dependencies-with-java-plugin), since they'll only be needed by your build tool (i.e. Gradle) for compiling the code i.e. Gradle will include them in the classpath while compiling the code but won't include them in the final JAR.

As you're using Mongo Spark Connector as well, which won't be present by default and you can either

1. Include it in your JAR, but I won't recommend this as it'll increase the size of your JAR
2. A better way is to ask Spark while submitting the job to include the package in your classpath, by adding the following argument. Spark will download the package from Local/Remote repository and will make sure it'll be available on the driver and all executors. You can also specify a repository using `--repositories`.

> --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can find those list of enhanced Jars in AWS document.

- [EMR 5.X](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html)
- [EMR 6.X](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-6x.html)

You don't need to create a fat-jar, because these jars are also added in the class path.

You can check the class paths via SSHing into the master instance.
Location of class paths -

- hive jars - `/usr/lib/hive`
- hadoop jars - `/usr/lib/hadoop`
- spark jars - `/usr/lib/spark`

---

You need to add the S3 location as maven repository in your gradle script, as you mention above. It's a public maven repository, so no credentials required.

Comment: are you saying we can use the normal gradle jar instead of using GradleShadow?

Comment: You need to use GradleShadow if you need fat jars for some libraries which is not available in the node.
These hive, hadoop, spark jars are already available in the runtime, so don't include them.  But if you need this for compiling the program then use `compileOnly` instead of `implementation`
If its onlt `runtimeOnly` then remove those.